# How to identify key from python dictionary that contains a substring value that corresponds with column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing

I have a dataframe that has a column, TaskName, that contains various strings of tasks. I also have a dictionary where the key is the category I would like to match it up to and the value is a list of substrings that identify the category. Each record of TaskName contains one of these dictionary values (once .lower() is applied to it) but I am having trouble finding an efficient solution to this problem. The dataframe has roughly 100,000 rows and the only solution I can come up with involves nested for loops and if statements that take too long to process (over 10 minutes). How can I fill in the category column of df with the corresponding catDict keys efficiently?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'JobId': [123,456,789],
                   'TaskName': ["Carpet [09743CARPET T/K 23525-346]", "QUALITY INSPECTION – 
                                 FINAL INSPECTION [2-93 QUALITY 43634]", "Install Glue Down 
                                 Wood [98053vPREFAB WOOD FLOOR 2935]"],
                   'Category': ["","",""]})

catDict = {'Frame': ['concrete pump truck', 'quality inspection - final inspection'],
           'Final': ['prefab wood', 'carpet t/k']}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me how you are mapping task to category. For example, would task 456's category = "Frame" because task 456's `TaskName` is "QUALITY INSPECTION - FINAL INSPECTION"?

If so, I would try to make `catDict` into a dataframe itself and then merge (`pd.merge`) to `df` using the common key. You'd need to create a new column in `df` that contains the key you're joining on (by doing some sort of `str` operation on `TaskName`). To make `catDict` a dataframe you could do something like `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(catDict, orient='index').transpose().melt()`

Comment: That is correct, I am trying to map TaskName to catDict by the catDict values that are contained within the full string of TaskName.

Comment: ok nice, did you try the solution I mentioned? that should work for your case.